# How to select all nodes where node attributes is in comma separated string (tokenized)

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

In php we do sth like:

```
 $values =explode(',',"A,B,C,D");
 if(in_array($value,$values)){
  // Do sthing 
 }
```

How can we do similar thing in XSLT . I need to select All nodes from xml file which has attributes @x in $commaSepartedString ,which is provided as parameter from command line

```
<xsl:for-each select="table[@name in $commaSeparatedString]">


</xsl:for-each>
```

## Edits

optionally I want to include all nodes by setting default value to parameter e.g

```
<xsl:param name="commaSeparatedString" select="'*'"/>
```

so a regx like thing seems more suitable

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With XSLT 2.0 use**:

```
table[$commaSeparatedString eq '*'
     or @name = tokenize($commaSeparatedString, ',')
     ]
```

Answer (score 2):

With XSLT 2.0 I would also use `tokenize` but then a simple comparison using `=` suffices e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each select="table[@name = tokenize('A,B,C,D,E', ',')]">...</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this:

```
<xsl:for-each 
   select="table[contains(concat(',', $commaSeparatedString, ','), 
                          concat(',', @name, ',')
                          )]">


</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: is there any regexp e.g @name in 'a|b|c' ?

Comment: If you're using XSLT 2.0, you should be able to use table[matches(@name, 'a|b|c|')] to do regex. Regex isn't available in standard XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XSLT2.0, you could make use of the **tokenize** function

```
<xsl:variable name="tokenizedValues" select="tokenize($values,',')"/>
```

This will split up your comma separated string into a list of values. You can then look for your **table** elements, by checking the **name** attribute was in the list

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="table[index-of($tokenizedValues,@name)]"/>
```

For example, consider the following XML

```
<tables>
<table name="A">1</table>
<table name="B">2</table>
<table name="C">3</table>
<table name="D">4</table>
<table name="E">5</table>
</tables>
```

When you use the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:variable name="values">A,B,C,D</xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="tokenizedValues" select="tokenize($values,',')"/>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="table[index-of($tokenizedValues,@name)]"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then the following is output

```
<table name="A">1</table>
<table name="B">2</table>
<table name="C">3</table>
<table name="D">4</table>
```